# Use a Particle Electron with Wi-Fi while in development

Tags: microcontrollers, wifi

Totally new to IoT, here. I got the new [Particle Electron](https://docs.particle.io/datasheets/electron-datasheet/) cellular IoT device. I used up 5 Mb in like three hours. I have no idea what took up all that data. That is the monthly limit so no I have to wait another month to use it or spend more money to develop on it.

I don't want to go through a months worth of data every day so I was wondering if there was a way hookup the Electron to Wi-Fi while I am developing it. Any good and easy to configure dongles? I have searched and can't find any way to do this easily.

Also, does that level of data usage seem abnormal? If so any ideas what happened? I accidentally tried to flash the tinker software on to OTA, but that was well before the 5 Mb data limit was reached. That only took like one Mb. So I guess hosting a variable on the cloud for like 2 hours took up 5 Mb.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

The Particle Electron has three free UART lines of which you can use one to connect an [ESP8266 based Wi-Fi module](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266-module-family).

[image: Particle Electron Pin Map]

The ESP can be controlled via [AT-Commands](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/images/5/53/Esp8266_at_instruction_set_en_v1.5.4_0.pdf) which is not that difficult to use. The manufacturer provides a lot of [document](https://espressif.com/en/support/download/documents) to help you getting started.

---

Furthermore, to make your life easier you could use a little C++ and OOP when doing your firmware.

You could define an [interface class](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/233) which is actually an abstract C++ class. This class would only define the functions your application code will use. Simple example functions:

- connect
- disconnect
- send
- receive

This would be your base class from which you could inherit a Cellular and a Wi-Fi class to implement the actual `connect/disconnect/send/receive` functions. These functions would be different for Wi-Fi and Cellular under the hood but the interface will be the same, and the result would be the same: **Internet connection**. The caller class/code would not know if it is a Cellular or Wi-Fi connection, it would only know that there are `connect/disconnect/send/receive` functions to use and there is **Internet**.

So when you do the testing you will have a Wi-Fi class instance and when you have finished debugging you could simply change it to a Cellular class instance.

This way you do not have to rewrite your code based on the used communication method.

Answer (score 8):

Have you read the [Particle Data Guide?](https://docs.particle.io/guide/getting-started/data/electron/) This shows a breakdown of how much data each message requires.

> A small, non-confirmable published event from an Electron is only 67 bytes.

On Ping:

> The initial ping results in 98 bytes, plus then the application's
>   acknowledgement is another 98 bytes. That's 196 bytes every 15
>   seconds, or almost 46 kilobytes per hour, just in pings.

On Reset:

> There are other communications that you may not even be aware of. For
>   instance, when an Electron turns on or is reset it has to register
>   with the cell towers and the Particle Cloud, and this set of messages
>   can use as much as 6KB

I didn't find any detail on the Particle website, but I'd expect you to be able to perform a reasonable amount of testing whilst tethered over USB. If nothing else, the cost of data will encourage you to debug your code carefully.